# How much room do windows 7-10 occupy on the UEFI System Partition­?

Tags: windows, partitioning, uefi

How much space do Windows 7-10 actually occupy on the UEFI System Partition (ESP)?

### my reasons:

I'm installing Linux on a new computer with a blank hard drive. I would like the option of installing Windows on it later if I need to, and I would like to know now while I am formatting the partition table how big I need to make the ESP in case I do decide to drink that kool-aid. I know there are [recommendations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition) to allocate ~200MiB of space, but I can safely assume that there is a massive safety margin I know I won't need. I do only have a small SSD so it's not like I'm made of gigabytes here.

As a pre-emptive stfu to all the people who say 200 megs isn't a lot, think of it as a 50% savings and you'll see why I care. The entire system is comprised of little pieces of 200MiB or less, and a 50% reduction in each of these components across the board is huge.

My own purposes notwithstanding, this would be a good thing to know in general and I'm sure there are others who require this information for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: Default size is 350MB and increase from 100MB from Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Here are the figures for several boot loaders from one of my systems:

- **OpenSUSE (GRUB):** 3.5 MiB
- **Mint 17.2 (GRUB):** 3.4 MiB
- **rEFInd 0.10.0:** 1.3 MiB
- **Windows 7:** 18 MiB
- **Windows 10:** 23 MiB

Despite the small size of the space occupied by the OS boot loaders, I recommend keeping an ESP of 550 MiB, for several reasons:

- OS boot loader needs may change. They may not change by an order of magnitude, but they could plausibly double or triple in the short- to medium-term. This is especially true if you end up keeping duplicated files around, as when you install a copy of a boot loader to the fallback filename. In the case of rEFInd, an update results in a backup copy of the old icons directory (840 KiB), so that nearly doubles the space required by rEFInd.
- You may need to store kernels on the ESP. Some Linux boot loaders and boot managers, such as ELILO, SYSLINUX, and gummiboot/systemd-boot, must read Linux kernels from the same partition from which they launch (or at best they make it hard to read kernels from elsewhere). If you decide to try such a boot loader, you'll need 30-50 MiB per kernel version on the ESP.
- Some EFIs have problems with FAT32 partitions smaller than 512 MiB. (Note that's 512 MiB, not 512 MB; see [here](http://stopabusingsiprefixes.org/stopabusing.html) to understand the difference.) The ESP is officially supposed to be FAT32, not FAT16 or FAT12. In particular, some EFIs seem to ignore some files on small FAT32 partitions, which leads to file-not-found problems. If you're very unlucky, you won't run into this problem at first, so you'll think everything's OK, but then when you need to access some seldom-used file (for a recovery operation, say), it will fail. Using FAT16 or FAT12 can sometimes work around this problem; however....
- Some programs, including both some EFIs and the Microsoft Windows installer (at least for Windows 7; I'm not sure about later versions) have problems with FAT16 (and probably FAT12) ESPs. Windows, in particular, refuses to recognize a FAT16 ESP as such. If you try to install on a computer with a FAT16 ESP, the Windows installer will automatically create a FAT32 ESP in addition to your existing FAT16 ESP, then choke after it reboots. I've run across one EFI that refuses to recognize FAT16 ESPs.

Between these factors, the safest approach is to create a FAT32 ESP that's at least 512 MiB in size. Given the potential for MB-vs-MiB confusion and the fact that some tools (like Linux's `mkdosfs`) switch from FAT16 to FAT32 at a strange value that's a little higher than 512 MiB, I generally give 550 MiB as my recommended value. That number is easy to remember and guarantees a FAT32 ESP, even if there's MB-vs-MiB confusion.

Of course, you can try a smaller ESP. It may work; but it may also *seem to* work, but create problems down the line. A 550 MiB ESP shouldn't be all that huge of a burden, even on a smallish SSD. For instance, that's 0.8% of a 64 GiB SSD. If losing less than one percent of your storage space is a hardship, then you really need more storage space!

Comment: Well, that's very helpful, thanks. I'm still going to make it 64 MiB, though. That's plenty of room for my purposes and if some software  fails because I use a small FAT32 partition, it's the software's fault and should be fixed. Unless it's absolutely critical I use that buggy software. Do you have an example of software that sometimes fails on small FAT32 devices?

Comment: Also, archlinux's kernel and initramfs are 7.4 MiB all together.

Comment: About the wasted space, I already pre-emptively addressed that in the question. You're looking at it the wrong way. It's the percent reduction that's important, which from my solution to yours is almost a full order of magnitude. Most software packages are around 50 megs each. If one programmer made theirs 10x bigger, that would only waste less than a percent of my hard drive, but if everybody who contributed software to my computer made it ten times bigger than it needed to be, I'd need nine more hard drives.

Comment: As I said in my answer, problems with small FAT32 partitions exist *in the firmware itself* -- at least, for some EFIs. Others are better. You'll be hard-pressed to avoid the firmware if you happen to have a buggy one. If yours is fine, then great. If not, then using a too-small FAT32 ESP will just cause you grief. Personally, I would not make the decision you're making, but of course it's your computer and you're welcome to do what you want with it. As to my "looking at it the wrong way," your logic is spurious; we *are* talking about just one use case, not all of them.

Comment: Oh, you never said the problem was in the firmware. That's different. In that case, I may be forced to use a massive EFI partition to accommodate a motherboard's firmware's crappiness. Still, Ramhound said 100MiB was Microsoft's default for a time. It seems unlikely *any* motherboard wouldn't accommodate Microsoft's defaults at any time. Can you give an example of a motherboard that requires at 512MiB ESP? My logic would have been sound if it were EFI programs with the bug and not the firmware. Buggy firmware really is a good reason to make an exception.

Comment: I'm trying to find more information on this problem with small FAT32 ESPs. I can't find anything. I have even found conflicting accounts saying a 500MiB ESP causes a failure that a 200MiB ESP fixes. Do you have any links with more information? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2021534&p=12088983#post12088983

Comment: I *did* say it was in the firmware: "Some EFIs have problems with FAT32 partitions smaller than 512 MiB." I've encountered this myself with the dreadful [Gigabyte hybrid EFI.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gb-hybrid-efi/) I've also seen discussions on the Arch Linux forums of such problems, but I don't have any URLs handy. Problems may not be apparent with boot loaders that read just one or two files from the ESP, since the problems cause random failures to read files, which typically affect only some files (maybe 1 in 4 files, at a guess).

Comment: I understand now that that's what you meant by "EFIs", but before I thought that meant some .EFI software images—not some EFI firmware implementations. Anyway, my 64MiB partition is working so far, so here's hoping I have non-buggy firmware! :D

Answer (score 0):

I just found a friend running windows 7. Its /boot/efi/Microsoft partition is 17.2MiB. Refind occupies another 7.1 MiB, making the total well under 32 MiB. It is unlikely Windows 8 or 10 uses much more than that, but it would be nice to know anyway. A 64MiB partition should be plenty.